# Enforce hook for branch creation in GitHub enterprise to not allow creating branches with names with certain regex pattern

Tags: bash, git, shell, github, githooks

We have a requirement where collaborators with write access to a GitHub repository should not be allowed to create branches with certain names. They can create locally but can't push to remote and also can't create directly using the GitHub UI. I know we can do something like this using git hook and enable that for that repo on the server side (on github enterprise server), but struggling to figure out how. Is that even possible?

If so I would like a shell script or something similar that I can use as hook to reject creation/push of any branches that start with the string release. I tried the below by adding a pre-receive hook on the github enterprise server but it doesn't do any good. Created a repo with a branch_hook.sh file and configured that hook and enabled it on a repo to test.

```
#!/bin/bash
branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
if [[ "$branch" == release* ]]; then
    echo "Your branch starts with release and is not allowed to be        
          pushed. Please create one that doesn't start with the release"
    exit 1
fi
```

It looks like GitHub server doesn't validate the branch name at all. If I execute it locally under a git repo, it works fine but git commit or push doesn't consider it at all.

Based on VonC's suggestions I tried this but doesn't seem to work.
Since I couldn't get the script at https://gist.github.com/caniszczyk/1327469
to work so tried something of my own.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Reject branch pushes that contain commits under those branches that have names starting with release

first_commit='0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'

while read -r oldrev newrev refname; do

    [ "$newrev" = "$first_commit" ] && continue


    [ "$oldrev" = "$first_commit" ] && range="$newrev" || range="$oldrev..$newrev"

    for commit in $(git rev-list "$range" --not --all); do
        if [[ "${refname#refs/heads/}" == release* ]]; then
    
            echo "ERROR: Your push was rejected because the commit"
            echo "ERROR: $commit in ${refname#refs/heads/}"
            echo "ERROR: is not allowed as ${refname#refs/heads/} is not supported branch name"
            echo "ERROR: Please fix your branch name or contact your repository admin."
            exit 1
        fi
    done

done
```

This works great when you create branch locally (just created newly or created newly and some commits added) and try to push to remote however there is no way to prevent creating branches using GitHub UI as the hook doesn't work in that scenario as its not a push event. So I am wondering how to get the script at https://gist.github.com/caniszczyk/1327469 to work if that is a true solution that works in both the cases.

Comment: Are you using github.com or an on-premises GitHub server?

Comment: on premis GitHub server or in other words enterprise GitHub

Comment: "doesn't seem to work.": first add some "`echo`" to make sure the `.pre-receive` hook is executed.

Comment: Kindly help me get rid of the lines that aren't needed for my use case so that i can modify it to just have the check for release* branch creation.I am having hard time to figure out what is oldrev and newrev here

Comment: @Ashley Hence the need to add some echo, in order to print the value of those variables.

Comment: if i just go line by line in the script and do oldrev=$(git rev-parse $1)
 a=$(expr "$oldrev" : "0*$")
echo $a
i get 0
so that main if doesn't get executed. How do i fix that code to just apply to my use case keeping it simple

Comment: another idea (compatible with github hosted as well) is to add branch protection with a required check that does not exist

Comment: But how would that prevent creation of new branches? Just curious

Comment: you'd be unable to push to a branch following those names that is protected because it does not satisfy the checks

Comment: That is correct. But my use case is to prevent the creation of the branch itself in the first place because the moment it gets created it will trigger a build in jenkins on that branch (its all automated that way and that is a whole different story).This hook i created works great by preventing anyone with write access to repository, to be able to push release* branches from their local, but no way to prevent creation from the UI in GitHub and branch protection applies only once the branch is created not at the time of branch creation

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an on-premise GitHub Enterprise server, you can add [n](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.18/admin/policies/creating-a-pre-receive-hook-script)

> A pre-receive hook script executes in a pre-receive hook environment on the GitHub Enterprise Server appliance.
> When you create a pre-receive hook script, consider the available input, output, exit-status and environment variables.

For example, [this hook](https://gist.github.com/caniszczyk/1327469) will enforce a naming convention policy on any branch pushed, which means it will disallow said push if the branch name does not follow a certain convention.

Comment: Thanks VonC. I am trying that script but unsure of how to enforce that naming convention for my branch. I want to enforce that any branches that start with release should not to be allowed to be pushed. Could you please point me where to enforce that in that script.

Comment: @Ashley See line 105: the `$refname` should be what you are after: make a pre-receive hooks which just print that argument: you should see something like `refs/head/<aBranchName>`. You can then change the `validate_ref()` function to `exit 1` if the `refname` includes "`/release.*`"

Comment: Thanks VonC. I tried as you suggested but looks like its not doing its thing. I am definitely missing something here. Hence looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and fix this using a [GitHub action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) such as this one:

```yaml
name: Fail when incorrect branch names are used
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - 'release*'
    - 'release*/**'

jobs:
  no_release_in_branch_names:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: If this is triggered, it should fail
        run: |
          __msg="::error::This branch ${GITHUB_REF_NAME} includes «release»; please don't use that in branch names
          Please rename the local branch with
              git checkout ${GITHUB_REF_NAME}
              git branch -m name_without_release
          echo "$__msg"
          echo ::set-output name=status::failure
          exit 1
```

That will prevent pushing to any branch created either locally or from the UI, by failing with the first commit that's done to that branch. Essentially, uses GitHub actions for a workflow that's triggered (and fails) just for the branch names that you don't want.